# Uniformly differentiable diffeomorphisms

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to prove that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism then $f$ restricted to a compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is uniformly differentiable, that is, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$, such that $|h|<\delta$ implies
$$|f(x+h)−f(x)−Df(x).h|<\varepsilon|h|$$ for every $x\in K$ (the number $\delta$ does not depend on $x$).

It seems that the $C^1$ hypothesis is essential, but even in this case I am not being able to prove this. Also, do you know any example of a diffeomorphism, defined in a compact subset, that is not uniformly differentiable?

Comment: for every $x\in \mathbb R^n?$

Comment: Sorry.. in the compact subset. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a $C^1$ function (notice that $n \ne m$ is not excluded).  Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.  For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $x \in K$ and $\lVert h \rVert  < \delta$ then $\lVert Df(x) - Df(x + h) \rVert < \epsilon$.

Take $\epsilon > 0$, $x \in K$ and $h$ with $\lVert h \rVert < \delta$.  By the $C^1$ Mean Value Theorem (see, e.g., Thm. 12 on p. 278 of:  [C. C. Pugh, *Real Mathematical Analysis*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/144192941X)), there holds
$$
f(x + h) - f(x) = \Bigl(\int\limits_{0}^{1} Df(x + t h) \, dt \Bigr) h.
$$
Therefore,
$$
f(x + h) - f(x) - Df(x) h = \Bigl(\int\limits_{0}^{1} (Df(x + t h) - Df(x)) \, dt \Bigr) h
$$
with
$$
\Bigl\lVert \int\limits_{0}^{1} (Df(x + t h) - Df(x)) \, dt \Bigr\rVert \le \int\limits_{0}^{1} \lVert Df(x + t h) - Df(x) \rVert \, dt < \epsilon.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One other question: this argument also proves that any power $f^k$ of $f$ is uniformly differentiable; is the number $\delta$ in the definition the same for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Consider the diffeomorphism $f$ of $(0, \infty)$ given by $f(x) = x^2$. At $x = 1$, $\lvert f^k(1 + h) - f^k(1) - (f^k)'(1) h \rvert = k (2k - 1) \lvert h \rvert + \text{ l.o.t.}$, which cannot be $o(\lvert h \rvert)$ *uniformly* in $k$.